# gulp-ruby-sass not a recognized command in Windows

Tags: windows, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying out gulp for the first time on a Windows Server 2012 VM. I'm normally a Mac user, so I'm a bit new to Windows & Powershell for dev tools like this. I installed Node.js & npm (and nothing else). I created the following basic Gulpfile to compile my Sass:

**Gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('Content/sass_new/application.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded', }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('Content/css'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('Content/sass_new/*', ['styles']);
})

gulp.task('default', ['styles']);
```

In Windows Powershell, I run the `gulp` command, and it outputs the following:

```
[10:02:57] Using gulpfile C:\[path to]\gulpfile.js
[10:02:57] Starting 'styles'...
[10:02:57] gulp-ruby-sass: 'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[10:02:57] Finished 'styles' after 316 ms
[10:02:57] Starting 'default'...
[10:02:57] Finished 'default' after 15 μs
```

Am I missing something here? Do I need to install Ruby or Sass? I thought to do that, I'd need a Ruby command prompt and PowerShell wouldn't have access to it. Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes that's right, you need to install `Ruby` and `Sass` to get `gulp-ruby-sass` working.

Begin by download the `Ruby` installer depending on your specs at [this address](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/). Once installed you supposed to have it on your system and accessible by `PowerShell` or the simple command line.

After, just run the command

```
gem install sass
```

And you're done.

Comment: Thanks. Still getting use to the interplay of all these various command prompts in Windows.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn Sorry, I'm not a native english speaker :)

Answer (score 0):

Download and Install Ruby : http://rubyinstaller.org/
set ruby location to Path Environment Variable 
restart the command prompt
and run `gem install sass`

That's it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12237787)

Comment: Yes Vini.g.fer, you are right, i just provided the link to download the ruby. Thanks for information