# How to get gulp to watch my sass file changes and create one css file?

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gulp

I am working on an application that is developed using ASP.NET MVC 5 framework. I am using Visual Studio 2013 to write my application.

I need to utilize [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to automate the process of compiling my sass file and publishing them into a bundle.css file.

To do that, here is what I have done

1. Installed [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/) on my machine
2. Installed [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) globally using `npm install -g gulp`
3. Created a file called `gulpfile.js` in the root project of the project
4. created the `package.json` file using `npm init` command
5. Added gulp to my development dependencies by executing the following command from the root of my project `npm install gulp --save-dev`
6. Added the code below to my `gulpfile.js`
7. From the command console I fired `gulp` command which displayed the following info

   Using gulpfile ...gulpfile.js

   Starting 'watch'...

   Finished 'watch' after 21 ms

   Starting 'default'...

   Finished 'default' after 31 µs

But when I write code into my `~/Assets/Sass/**/*.sass` nothing gets saved into `~/Public/Css/bundle.css` as expected

Here is what `gulpfile.js` looks like

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
      sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

// Default task which will be be fired when the runner is started
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

// listener task
gulp.task('watch', function(){

    //Watch any change in the sass directory and trigger the "compileSass" for every save
    gulp.watch('~/Assets/Sass/**/*.sass', ['compileSass']);

});

// Task to compile the sass files
gulp.task('compileSass', () =>
    sass('~/Assets/Sass/**/*.sass')
        .on('error', sass.logError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('~/Public/Css/bundle.css'))
);
```

What am I missing here? How can I get the watched to watch and fire the tasks after each save?

**Updated**

I switch from using `gulp-ruby-sass` plugin into using [gulp-scss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-scss). Now, I got the task to run every time I save a `scss` file but for some reason it wont update the destination file.

Here is how my `gulpfile.js` file looks like

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
      scss = require('gulp-scss');

// Default task which will be be fired when the runner is started
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

// listener task
gulp.task('watch', function(){

    //Watch any change in the "Sass" directory and trigger the "compileScss" for every save
    gulp.watch('./Assets/Scss/**/*.scss', ['compileScss']);

});

// Task to compile the "Scss" files
gulp.task('compileScss', function () {
    gulp.src('./Assets/Scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(scss({ "bundleExec": true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./Public/Css/bundle.css'));
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure gulp understands the tilde in the path (`~`). Try starting your paths with `./` instead of `~/`. Also, I would verify if your `compileSass` task works as expected when invoked directly (without the watch).

Comment: Thank you for that useful hint! now I am getting a new error after changing `~` to `.` .  here is the error `'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Error in plugin 'gulp-ruby-sass' Message: Gem undefined is not installed.`

Comment: If you want to use `gulp-ruby-sass`, you may need to have Ruby as well as the sass gem installed on your machine - refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937506/gulp-ruby-sass-not-a-recognized-command-in-windows). However, you may find it easier instead to just use [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass), unless you have a good reason to use gulp-ruby-sass.

Comment: @SergeyK thank you. I switch to using `gulp-scss` and now every time I save a file with the extension `scss` I can see see a new line in the console that say `Starting `compileScss`.... Finished `compileScss` but the file bundle.css does not get populated. and yes I add code in my site.scss files. Please have a look at my updated question to see my current code

Comment: My next recommendation is to verify that it's actually finding your scss files. Install the [gulp-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug) plugin, then pipe the output from `gulp.src('./Assets/Scss/**/*.scss')` to it by adding the following right after that line: `.pipe(debug({}))`. Then run your `compileScss` task and verify that it's actually finding the files (it should list all the filenames that matched your glob pattern - make sure it doesn't say something like "0 items").

Comment: Thank you for that info. It displayed this file Assets\Scss\Site.scss and it gave me 1 item. Could it be that it is not finding my destination file? is `.pipe(gulp.dest('./Public/Css/bundle.css'))` the correct way to tell it where the combined destination file should be?

Comment: That's the correct way to specify the destination. Probably something is going wrong in the call to `scss`, and there is no error handler in the stream so the error is being swallowed. You can try adding an `.on('error', ...)` handler to the stream (you can install [gulp-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-util) and pipe it to `gutil.log`). I would also strongly recommend you use [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) rather than [gulp-scss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-scss), since gulp-scss is clearly marked obsolete.

Comment: Tangent: if `gulp.task('default', ['watch']);` is really your entire default task, you could simplify things a little with `gulp.task('default', function(){ gulp.watch('./Assets/Scss/**/*.scss', ['compileScss']) });`

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the ***require*** for **gulp-watch**:

```
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
```

**From [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch#watchglob-options-callback):**

> watch(glob, [options, callback]) Creates a watcher that will spy on
>   files that are matched by glob which can be a glob string or array of
>   glob strings.
>
> Returns a pass through stream that will emit vinyl files (with
>   additional event property) that corresponds to event on file-system.

You have to provide a function. Meaning that a task name is not sufficient.

Try using gulp-batch to run some tasks withing your watch:

```
npm install gulp-batch --save-dev
```

**Your watch task:**

```
// listener task
gulp.task('watch', function(){

   var watch = require('gulp-watch');
   var batch = require('gulp-batch');

    //Watch any change in the sass directory and trigger the "compileSass" for every save
    watch('~/Assets/Sass/**/*.sass', batch(function (events, done) {
        // run your compileSass task
        gulp.start('compileSass', done);

    }));

});
```

---

Edit:

You can run tasks from Visual Studio 2015 in the "Task Runner Explorer" window.

However, if you have a prompt running **gulp-watch** it should have the same effect and run your compile task when it detect changes to the files that you are watching regardless of where they were edited.

Comment: now the console does not even look like it is watching. it simply executed the command and prompt you for a new command. I belive gulp comes with a watch api which allows you to watch the files. Here is a tutorial that shows how to use it which I have followed https://scotch.io/tutorials/automate-your-tasks-easily-with-gulp-js

Comment: My apologies. To be honest I have never used gulp's built-in watch. Even the gulp evangelists suggest the plug-in gulp-watch. So I assumed that was the standard. In any case, if you get it working I would be interested in knowing how you got it to work. I wish I could help you more.

Comment: It's not at all uncommon to use `gulp.watch`. `gulp-watch` has some great functionality, but in a straightforward case like this there's no need to add the extra node-modules weight and gulpfile weight. @WilmerSaint you can learn `gulp.watch` in a few seconds - check out the "sass:watch" task in https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass

Answer (score 0):

Basic things to check are folder location existence, file names, and read/write permissions.

Example gulpfile.js that uses `gulp.watch` and `gulp-load-plugins` in a Zurb Foundation 6 project using ([foundation-cli](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-cli)).

Note that  `.pipe(gulp.dest('../your/path/css'));`
does not include a `~` or specify a file name or extension.  It only specifies a path.  The file placed in that path is given the default name of `style.css` since the source files name is `style.scss`. See line `gulp.src('scss/style.scss')`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $    = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

// Multiple locations of SCSS to combine
var sassPaths = [
  'bower_components/foundation-sites/scss',
  'bower_components/motion-ui/src'
];

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('scss/style.scss')           // SCSS Source file
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths,
      outputStyle: 'compressed'               // if css compressed **file size**
    })
      .on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../your/path/css'));     // OUTPUT Destination
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass'], function() {
  gulp.watch(['scss/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);   // FILES to Watch
});
```